# evaluating a polynomial for a given value

Tags: haskell

Hi I have a algebraic type Poly a

```
data Poly a = X

| Coef a

| Sum (Poly a) (Poly a)

| Prod (Poly a) (Poly a)

deriving Show
```

I want to write a function that will evaluate poly a when given a number n

```
polyValue :: Num a => Poly a -> a -> a

polyValue p n =
```

I'm having a hard time figuring this out and feel like I'm not actually understanding the type Poly a. Thank you for the help.

Comment: There are four cases to consider. Can you think of what the value of `polyValue (Coef c) n` should be? How about the value of `polyValue X n`?

Comment: polyValue (Coef c) n should multiply n * (Coef c) and polyValue X n should just = n?

Comment: You’re right about `polyValue X n = n`. I’m not sure about `Coef`. Consider: is the polynomial 2x + 1 representable as a `Poly`? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: yeah it is. 2x + 1 would look like (Sum (Prod (Coef 2) X) (Coef 1)). so the coef should just be c then

Comment: Correct! Now that you can evaluate `Poly`s that don’t involve other `Poly`s, do you have any tentative implementations for `polyValue (Sum p1 p2) n` and `polyValue (Prod p1 p2) n`?

Comment: yeah, I used polyValue (Sum p1 p2) n  = (polyValue p1 n) + (polyValue p2 n) and * for polyValue (Prod p1 p2). Thanks for the help Ry

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is homework or not, so I will try to guide you without giving you the exact answer. You have declared a sum type with four constructors: `X`, `Coef a`, `Sum (Poly a) (Poly a)` and `Prod (Poly a) (Poly a)`. On the left hand side of your function you can match each of the constructors and define a unique function body that returns the same type as the type signature. I leave the function body empty for you to fill out.

```hs
polyValue :: Num a => Poly a -> a -> a
polyValue X n =
polyValue (Coef a) n =
polyValue (Sum a b) n = -- you can call polyValue on a and b because they are Poly types
polyValue (Prod a b) n = -- you can call polyValue on a and b because they are Poly types
```